# Where is "struct _ntl_gbigint_body" defined?

Tags: c++, ntl

I am browsing [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/) code, but can' find `struct _ntl_gbigint_body` definition:

```
$ grep -r _ntl_gbigint_body *
include/NTL/ZZ.h:WrappedPtr<_ntl_gbigint_body, Deleter> rep;
include/NTL/lip.h:struct _ntl_gbigint_body;
include/NTL/lip.h:typedef _ntl_gbigint_body *_ntl_gbigint;
Binary file src/RR.o matches
.....
Binary file src/GF2E.o matches
src/lip.cpp:typedef WrappedPtr<_ntl_gbigint_body, _ntl_gbigint_deleter> _ntl_gbigint_wrapped;
Binary file src/mat_ZZ_p.o matches
......
```

I am just curious Where it is defined.

Comment: I have no clue, but maybe there is a C++ trick somewhere in `lip.h`? I will add the C++ tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussing with Victor Shoup, the author of `NTL`, he gave the answer:

> It's actually never declared.
>   A pointer to it is like a void pointer, but with better error checking.